# UIPageViewController inside a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

**Swift only**

I created a fully functional `UIPageViewController` with 3 different `UIViewController`'s, is it possible to create another `UIPageViewController` inside one of those `UIViewController`?

For example, i am on the last `UIViewController` if i swipe to the left(<--) i can access another `UIViewController` and if i swipe to the right(-->) i return to the last`UIViewController`.

Check Image.

[image]

**I used segues so you know which** `UIViewController`**that is connected with which** `UIPageViewController`

**Swift only**

Comment: Did you try it and see what happens?

Comment: Yeah, i slide to an empty `viewController` with neither the red or the green screen available. It is just white.

Comment: Your last page from the first navigation stack should segue to the second `PageViewController`, not to a ViewController.

Comment: Oh it works, that was simple @Tim

Comment: added it as an answer. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last page from the first navigation stack should segue to the second PageViewController, not to a ViewController